# Is it possible to have vim use different colors than the iTerm profile?

Tags: vim, iterm2

My vim currently uses the colors defined by my current iTerm profile.

Is it possible to have vim use a separate set of defined colors? This way I could have one look for my terminal and a different look for my vim.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes!** You can use a colorscheme for vim different than terminal.

Vim allows using different types of colorschemes. You can change them at any time.
You can use different colorschemes for different filetypes also!

Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7331940/how-to-get-the-list-of-all-installed-color-schemes-in-vim for some basics about colorscheme.

You can download external plugins for colorschemes. You can also define your own colorscheme. Refer vim help about this to know more.